# Isolation barrier in digital signal isolator

Tags: digital-communications

Could anyone comment on why a capacitor is better than an inductor according to the statement below:

"In general, an isolation barrier implemented with capacitors is better for passing signals to low impedance nodes than a barrier formed from inductors."​
​
source: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/8a/f0/44/e4b751f0ae6805/US7923710.pdf

Thanks.​

Comment: I very much doubt the generality of the statement you cite. It probably has to do with the particular cirucmstances the inventor had in mind.

Comment: The paragraphs before the statement give some clues .